# NEED HELP..! Bearer token showing [object object] and app crashed with UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection - Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, powerbi

trying integrate PowerBI using NodeJS as per this official MS example available [GITHUB](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master/NodeJS/Embed%20for%20your%20customers/AppOwnsData)
I'm not more into NodeJS. But trying to understand how this api working.

trying to call the below endpoint via Ajax onload

```
app.get('/getSingRpt', function (req, res) {
    try {
        let pbiRec = embedToken.getEmbedParamsForSingleReport()
        console.log('getSingRpt====>', pbiRec)
        res.status(200).json();
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({
            status: 'failed',
            message: 'Unable to fetch the report'
        });
    }
});
```

the api then hit service like below

```
async function getEmbedParamsForSingleReport(workspaceId, reportId, additionalDatasetId) {
    const reportInGroupApi = `https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/${workspaceId}/reports/${reportId}`;
    const headers = await getRequestHeader();
    const result = await fetch(reportInGroupApi, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: headers,
    })
    console.log('From service===>>>>> headers', headers);
    console.log('result ===>>>>> headers', result);
   
    if (!result.ok) {
        throw result;
    }
    const resultJson = await result.json();
    const reportDetails = new PowerBiReportDetails(resultJson.id, resultJson.name, resultJson.embedUrl);
    const reportEmbedConfig = new EmbedConfig();

    reportEmbedConfig.reportsDetail = [reportDetails];

    let datasetIds = [resultJson.datasetId];
    if (additionalDatasetId) {
        datasetIds.push(additionalDatasetId);
    }

    reportEmbedConfig.embedToken = await getEmbedTokenForSingleReportSingleWorkspace(reportId, datasetIds, workspaceId);
    return reportEmbedConfig;
}
```

Followed by the **authentication.js** getting called

```
 const getAccessToken = async function () {
        let adal = require("adal-node");
        let AuthenticationContext = adal.AuthenticationContext;
        let config = require(__dirname + "/../config/config.json");
    
        let authorityUrl = config.authorityUri;
        if (config.authenticationMode.toLowerCase() === "masteruser") {
            let context = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUrl);
    
            return new Promise(
                (resolve, reject) => {
                    context.acquireTokenWithUsernamePassword(config.scope, config.pbiUsername, config.pbiPassword, config.clientId, function (err, tokenResponse) {
    
                        if (err) {
                            reject(tokenResponse == null ? err : tokenResponse);
                        }
                        resolve(tokenResponse);
                    })
                }
            );
    
        } else if (config.authenticationMode.toLowerCase() === "serviceprincipal") {
            authorityUrl = authorityUrl.replace("common", config.tenantId);
            let context = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUrl);
            try {
                
            } catch (error) {
                
            }
            return new Promise(
                (resolve, reject) => {
                    context.acquireTokenWithClientCredentials(config.scope, config.clientId, config.clientSecret, function (err, tokenResponse) {
                        if (err) {
                            reject(tokenResponse == null ? err : tokenResponse);
                        }
                        resolve(tokenResponse);
                    })
                }
            );
        }
    }
```

I was having some authentication issue initially when trying to calling **getEmbedParamsForSingleReport()** from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/blob/master/NodeJS/Embed%20for%20your%20customers/AppOwnsData/src/embedConfigService.js)

Somehow I fixed that authentication issue where I can able get the **access-token** now. after getting  token successfully, I've got the below error

For my case, `else` part suppose to work, but as soon as getting the **access-token** successfully app went to crashed

Could someone tell me how to resolve?

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
> error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
> without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
> with .catch().

[image]

Comment: token is returned within accessToken field, you are returning the whole payload. p.s. use the msal library helps you out with ad auth

Comment: @quirimmo can you pls share me some implement examples.. Im actually node belong from NodeJs so struggling to complete this node part

Answer (score 1):

I can't test your code since I don't have the configuration file to be able to authenticate against the external service, but I have reviewed your code and you have quite a few errors in terms of good programming practices and other errors that affect the operation of your code. I have taken the liberty of rewriting your code so that you can find the error more clearly. Here are some tips to make your future code better:

1. The "require" statements are always outside the definition of your
   functions.
2. Use "const" instead of "let" for variables that will not change
   their value.
3. Use "promise" or "async / await" but never both at the same time,
   because then you get the "Promise not resolved" error.
4. Make sure that you always resolve or reject promises and that they
   are never left unfinished.
5. Do not repeat code unnecessarily and use tabs to be able to
   visualize it in a clearer way.
6. You don't need several promises within the function, just have one
   that resolves or rejects in each case.
7. Be careful with "if / else if" and make sure to always put an "else"
   at the end to ensure all possibilities.
8. Try to change your path to the configuration file so that it is a
   relative path, do not use absolute paths (I have not changed that
   part of your code because I do not know the structure of your
   project.

   ```
   const adal = require('adal-node');
   const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json');
   const getAccessToken = () => {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       try {
         const authMode = config.authenticationMode.toLowerCase();
         const AuthenticationContext = adal.AuthenticationContext;
         let authorityUrl = config.authorityUri;
         if (authMode === 'masteruser') {
           new AuthenticationContext(
             authorityUrl,
           ).acquireTokenWithUsernamePassword(
             config.scope,
             config.pbiUsername,
             config.pbiPassword,
             config.clientId,
             (err, token) => {
               if (err) reject(err);
               resolve(token);
             },
           );
         } else if (authMode === 'serviceprincipal') {
           authorityUrl = authorityUrl.replace('common', config.tenantId);
           new AuthenticationContext(
             authorityUrl,
           ).acquireTokenWithClientCredentials(
             config.scope,
             config.clientId,
             config.clientSecret,
             (err, token) => {
               if (err) reject(err);
               resolve(token);
             },
           );
         } else {
           reject(new Error('Unknown auth mode'));
         }
       } catch (err) {
         console.error(err);
         reject(err);
       }
     });
   };
   ```

Finally, you can call your function like this:

```
getAccessToken()
.then((token) => console.log(token))
.catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

I hope I have helped. A greeting and good luck!!

**EDIT**
Okay, well this afternoon I'll try to take a look at it and fix the problems you have. I am currently seeing several with the naked eye.
You have to change your implementation of / getSignRpt to wait for the return result, since "getEmbedParamsForSingleReport" is asynchronous:

```
app.get('/getSingRpt', (req, res) => {
  embedToken
    .getEmbedParamsForSingleReport()
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      res.status(200).send({success: true, data: result});
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.error(e);
      res
        .status(400)
        .send({success: false, message: 'Unable to fetch the report'});
    });
});
```

You also have to pass the 3 parameters to the "getEmbedParamsForSingleReport" function, you are currently not passing anything to it when you invoke it.

Comment: Mauel Martinez .. thank you so much for your quick response. I just copy and pasted your modified code, still seeing same unhandled error along with ` error: 'TypeError: auth.getAccessToken is not a function'` when i called getAccessToken method inside `getEmbedParamsForSingleReport()`  at line# 2

Comment: I need a little more information to help you. Tell me all the libraries you are using and how I can build an example to provide you with code that can work correctly. I don't know where the function you are telling me about is implemented.

Comment: Manuel Martinez actually all the implementations are here [GITHUB](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master/NodeJS/Embed%20for%20your%20customers/AppOwnsData)

Comment: in this official MS [playground](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/getreportingroup#code-try-0) where you can give Azure AD credentials if you have..

Comment: is there anything need to change [here](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/blob/master/NodeJS/Embed%20for%20your%20customers/AppOwnsData/public/js/index.js)
Getting **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined**
at line:79

Comment: `auth.getAccessToken` is not a function inside `getRequestHeader()` in embetConfigService.js